# Verbs that can go with "contempt"

Tags: word-request, expressions

What are the verbs that can be used to express the idea of "reducing someone's contempt"? Let's say I meet a person who has a deep contempt for my favorite president XYZ. I want to change his opinions on XYZ. Now should I say "I want to **reduce/lessen** his contempt for president XYZ"? I've done some research on this but failed to find any relevant examples to back up either of them.

Please note that I want to use the construction of **"verb + someone's + contempt"**. Thanks.

Comment: Please explain what research you did so other people don't needlessly duplicate it (among other reasons). I was able to find relevant results both with a simple web search and at https://books.google.com/ngrams/, so I'm curious to hear what you tried.

Comment: to lessen or attenuate. Here's a trick: To feel contempt for someone, so lessen the contempt x feels for y.